# How to set Access Token Timeout for native application in ADFS application group?

Tags: oauth-2.0, adfs

We have a mobile application authenticating using ADFS 2019 application group. It receives an access token which is valid for 60 mins. How to configure access token lifetime for native application which doesn't use relying party. All the questions/forums talk about TokenLifeTime for relying party but native applications doesn't use it.

Tried setting it for web api application created in same application group but has no impact. I'm able to configure Refresh Token lifetime (WebSSOlifetime) on ADFS level but can't find anyway to do the same for Access Token.